# Unity launcher hides too fast in autohide mode

Tags: unity, launcher

I find that the Unity launcher in the Auto-hide option hides itself too fast. Just as I click something, the launcher is gone.

I don't want to set it to "never hide", I just want it to wait, say, 3-4 seconds after I click on an icon before disappearing.

I have seen related questions, but they all talk about making it disappear faster.

Comment: I don't know of any options for that, but I haven't used any of the unofficial tools like Ubuntu Tweak et al.  I don't even use auto-hide these days.  But I'm curious, is it that: you are ready to make another click, but the Launcher is already gone?  Or is it visually disruptive to disappear that soon?  Thanks.

Comment: The hiding animation is too fast, so I get lost.. I always feel like: What in the nine gods did I just click? It also hides fast if I place the mouse above it, so I also have no way of telling which windows are actually open.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like an unpleasant feeling.  For when the mouse is right over it, there's been a recent change, in the current development release.  I don't know if it will count as an answer, but the info doesn't format well in a comment, so I'll put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the times when the pointer is over the Launcher, that's been changed in the latest versions of Unity, available only in the development release, until 12.10 comes out.

```
unity (6.4.0-0ubuntu1) quantal-proposed

- Launcher - Launcher should never autohide when the cursor is positioned 
  over the Launcher (e.g. When a spread ends) (LP: #745707)

Thu, 30 Aug 2012
```

That was [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/745707).

There's an [ongoing bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/1053978) to keep it from disappearing when you're dragging icons to it.

Maybe these will be interesting, or helpful when the upgrades arrive for you.